# How to best handle data stored in different locations in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

My current workflow in BigQuery is as follows:

(1) query data in a public repository (stored in the US), (2) write it to a table in my repository, (3) export a csv to a cloud bucket and (4) download the csv on the server I work on and (5) work with that on the server.

The problem I have now, is that the server I work on is located in EU. Thus, I have to pay quite some fees for transfering data between my US bucket and my EU server. I could now go ahead and locate my bucket in EU, but then I still have the problem that I would transfer data from the US (BigQuery) to EU (bucket). So I could also set my dataset in bq to be located in the EU, but then I cant do any queries anylonger, because the data in the public repository is located in the US, and queries between different locations are not allowed.

Does anyone have an idea of how to approach this?

Comment: What's the amount of data and roughly what figure you want to avoid paying?

Comment: The amount of csv data that I need to transfer in the end is around 3GB each time. However, I am doing this quite frequently. It sums to some $ per day.

Comment: Actually what do you pay here?

Comment: Well, I pay the "inter-continental transfer" listed here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing My daily amount depends on the number of queries I do; I e.g. had 2$ yesterday.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to get a cheap VM from a no-name company but server located in the US with no such pricing, and use that as an intermediate step?

Comment: That might be a solution, but a very impractical one as it would require some more steps in my workflow that cannot be directly piped. There has to be a better solution to circumvent this.

Comment: Maybe the problem can be addressed otherwise, what's that you try to solve, and you need to download regularly such big content.

Comment: Well I have some complex queries where I store the results in a table. Then, I do analyses on that data, but I somehow need to get it. The best and fastest way is to do it via export/import csv; all other approaches like direct queries via API fail miserably due to the data size.

Comment: Hey Barsch! While this is definitely a good and interesting question, I'm not entirely sure this is on-topic for Stack. No worries my friend, we're not abandoning you though! I would suggest posting your question on Google Groups so it's more on topic there (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine). Also consider including some more info, namely : Which public data are you querying? (if it's one of those we offer, it might be possible to make a Feature Request to dupe it into EU, which would save you some trouble). Also, is there a reason why you need the server in the EU?

Comment: Okay, I was asked to ask it here on stackoverflow. Anyways, I posted it as well in the google group.

Answer (score 7):

One way to copy a BigQuery dataset from one region to another is to take advantage of the [Storage Data Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/). It doesn't get around the fact that you still have to [pay for bucket-to-bucket network traffic](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-pricing), but might save you some CPU time on copying data to a server in the EU.

The flow would be to:

1. Extract all the BigQuery tables into a bucket in the same region as the tables. (Recommend Avro format for best fidelity in data types and fastest loading speed.)
2. Run a storage transfer job to copy the extracted files from the starting location bucket to a bucket in the destination location.
3. Load all the files into a BigQuery dataset located in the destination location.

**Python example:**

```
# Copyright 2018 Google LLC
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

import datetime
import sys
import time

import googleapiclient.discovery
from google.cloud import bigquery
import json
import pytz


PROJECT_ID = 'swast-scratch'  # TODO: set this to your project name
FROM_LOCATION = 'US'  # TODO: set this to the BigQuery location
FROM_DATASET = 'workflow_test_us'  # TODO: set to BQ dataset name
FROM_BUCKET = 'swast-scratch-us'  # TODO: set to bucket name in same location
TO_LOCATION = 'EU'  # TODO: set this to the destination BigQuery location
TO_DATASET = 'workflow_test_eu'  # TODO: set to destination dataset name
TO_BUCKET = 'swast-scratch-eu'  # TODO: set to bucket name in destination loc

# Construct API clients.
bq_client = bigquery.Client(project=PROJECT_ID)
transfer_client = googleapiclient.discovery.build('storagetransfer', 'v1')


def extract_tables():
    # Extract all tables in a dataset to a Cloud Storage bucket.
    print('Extracting {}:{} to bucket {}'.format(
        PROJECT_ID, FROM_DATASET, FROM_BUCKET))

    tables = list(bq_client.list_tables(bq_client.dataset(FROM_DATASET)))
    extract_jobs = []
    for table in tables:
        job_config = bigquery.ExtractJobConfig()
        job_config.destination_format = bigquery.DestinationFormat.AVRO
        extract_job = bq_client.extract_table(
            table.reference,
            ['gs://{}/{}.avro'.format(FROM_BUCKET, table.table_id)],
            location=FROM_LOCATION,  # Available in 0.32.0 library.
            job_config=job_config)  # Starts the extract job.
        extract_jobs.append(extract_job)

    for job in extract_jobs:
        job.result()

    return tables


def transfer_buckets():
    # Transfer files from one region to another using storage transfer service.
    print('Transferring bucket {} to {}'.format(FROM_BUCKET, TO_BUCKET))
    now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
    transfer_job = {
        'description': '{}-{}-{}_once'.format(
            PROJECT_ID, FROM_BUCKET, TO_BUCKET),
        'status': 'ENABLED',
        'projectId': PROJECT_ID,
        'transferSpec': {
            'transferOptions': {
                'overwriteObjectsAlreadyExistingInSink': True,
            },
            'gcsDataSource': {
                'bucketName': FROM_BUCKET,
            },
            'gcsDataSink': {
                'bucketName': TO_BUCKET,
            },
        },
        # Set start and end date to today (UTC) without a time part to start
        # the job immediately.
        'schedule': {
            'scheduleStartDate': {
                'year': now.year,
                'month': now.month,
                'day': now.day,
            },
            'scheduleEndDate': {
                'year': now.year,
                'month': now.month,
                'day': now.day,
            },
        },
    }
    transfer_job = transfer_client.transferJobs().create(
        body=transfer_job).execute()
    print('Returned transferJob: {}'.format(
        json.dumps(transfer_job, indent=4)))

    # Find the operation created for the job.
    job_filter = {
        'project_id': PROJECT_ID,
        'job_names': [transfer_job['name']],
    }

    # Wait until the operation has started.
    response = {}
    while ('operations' not in response) or (not response['operations']):
        time.sleep(1)
        response = transfer_client.transferOperations().list(
            name='transferOperations', filter=json.dumps(job_filter)).execute()

    operation = response['operations'][0]
    print('Returned transferOperation: {}'.format(
        json.dumps(operation, indent=4)))

    # Wait for the transfer to complete.
    print('Waiting ', end='')
    while operation['metadata']['status'] == 'IN_PROGRESS':
        print('.', end='')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(5)
        operation = transfer_client.transferOperations().get(
            name=operation['name']).execute()
    print()

    print('Finished transferOperation: {}'.format(
        json.dumps(operation, indent=4)))


def load_tables(tables):
    # Load all tables into the new dataset.
    print('Loading tables from bucket {} to {}:{}'.format(
        TO_BUCKET, PROJECT_ID, TO_DATASET))

    load_jobs = []
    for table in tables:
        dest_table = bq_client.dataset(TO_DATASET).table(table.table_id)
        job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
        job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.AVRO
        load_job = bq_client.load_table_from_uri(
            ['gs://{}/{}.avro'.format(TO_BUCKET, table.table_id)],
            dest_table,
            location=TO_LOCATION,  # Available in 0.32.0 library.
            job_config=job_config)  # Starts the load job.
        load_jobs.append(load_job)

    for job in load_jobs:
        job.result()


# Actually run the script.
tables = extract_tables()
transfer_buckets()
load_tables(tables)
```

The preceding sample uses google-cloud-bigquery library for BigQuery API and google-api-python-client for Storage Data Transfer API.

Note that this sample does not account for partitioned tables.

Comment: A few other options (using Composer and Dataflow) are now listed in SO questions here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/53077678/2877278

Answer (score 0):

No matter what, you have data in the US that you need in the EU, so I think you have two options:

1. You could continue to pay many smaller fees to move your reduced datasets from the US to the EU as you're doing today.
2. You could pay the one-off fee to transfer the original public BQ dataset from the US to your own dataset in the EU. From then on, all queries you run stay in the same region, and you have no more trans-continental transfers.

It really depends on how many queries you plan to do. If it's not a lot, then the way you're doing things today seems like it'd be the most efficient. If it's a lot, then moving the data once (paying the up-front fee) might work out cheaper.

Maybe Google has some magical way to make this better, but as far as I can tell, you're dealing with lots of data on one side of the Atlantic that you need on the other side, and moving it across that wire costs money.