# Best way to migrate large amount of data from US dataset to EU dataset in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have many TBs in about 1 million tables in a single BigQuery project hosted in multiple datasets that are located in the US.  I need to move all of this data to datasets hosted in the EU.  What is my best option for doing so?

- I'd export the tables to Google Cloud Storage and reimport using load jobs, but there's a 10K limit on load jobs per project per day
- I'd do it as queries w/"allow large results" and save to a destination table, but that doesn't work cross-region

The only option I see right now is to reinsert all of the data using the BQ streaming API, which would be cost prohibitive.

What's the best way to move a large volume of data in many tables cross-region in BigQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to best handle data stored in different locations in Google BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767245/how-to-best-handle-data-stored-in-different-locations-in-google-bigquery)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. Use load jobs, and contact Google Cloud Support to ask for a quota exception. They're likely to grant 100k or so on a temporary basis (if not, contact me, `tigani@google`, and I can do so).
2. Use federated query jobs. That is, move the data into a GCS bucket in the EU, then re-import the data via BigQuery queries with GCS data sources. More info [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/federated-data-sources).

I'll also look into whether we can increase this quota limit across the board.

Answer (score 5):

You can copy dataset using [BigQuery Copy Dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets) (in/cross-region).  The copy dataset UI is similar to copy table. Just click "copy dataset" button from the source dataset, and specify the destination dataset in the pop-up form. See screenshot below. Check out the public documentation for more use cases.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A few other options that are now available since Jordan answered a few years ago. These options might be useful for some folks:

1. Use Cloud Composer to orchestrate the export and load via GCS buckets. See [here](https://gweb-cloudblog-publish.appspot.com/products/data-analytics/how-to-transfer-bigquery-tables-between-locations-with-cloud-composer/amp/).
2. Use Cloud Dataflow to orchestrate the export and load via GCS buckets. See [here](https://medium.com/weareservian/how-to-transfer-bigquery-tables-between-locations-with-cloud-dataflow-9582acc6ae1d).

Disclaimer: I wrote the article for the 2nd option (using Cloud Dataflow).