# Move Tables from US dataset to EU dataset

Tags: location, dataset, google-bigquery

I have created some projects  on Google Cloud Platform (and Bigquery) that were located in US. Now I want to create datasets only in EU. Is there any way to copy those tables from US dataset to EU dataset without downloading data locally??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to best handle data stored in different locations in Google BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767245/how-to-best-handle-data-stored-in-different-locations-in-google-bigquery)

Comment: I answer this exact question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49582122/101923 (Apparently I can't post duplicate answers, my answer here was deleted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the following recommendation from a member of the subteam that owns the import pipeline:

1. extract to GCS
2. copy to GCS bucket in other region
3. import into BQ

I'm afraid we don't have anything more streamlined than that at this time

Answer (score 1):

There is option to use cross region copy. Example of command:

```
bq mk --transfer_config --project_id=your-project-id --data_source=cross_region_copy --target_dataset=your-target-dataset --display_name='description' --params='{"source_dataset_id":"your-source-dataset","source_project_id":"your-project-id","overwrite_destination_table":"true"}'
```

This command copy the dataset between regions and replace all existing tables in the target dataset. I did not find way how to copy only particular tables.

Answer (score 0):

Copy requires both Source and Destination Tables to be in same location
So your option is to extract your data from Source Table to Cloud Storage and then load from Cloud Storage to Destination

Answer (score -1):

According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables) documentation on copying BQ tables, it is mentioned that

"When copying tables, the destination dataset must reside in the same location as the table being copied. For example, you cannot copy a table from an EU-based dataset to a US-based dataset."

As of today, we cannot copy tables between different regions directly.

Answer (score -4):

I believe you can use the Copy Table functionality for this. Click on the dropdown next to the table's name in the UI and select Copy Table.